Change date format DatePickerDialog- Android studio Java
Does anyone know how to change the date format in DatePickerDialog in Android studio in Java, I need like "Mon, May 6" I need like this format instead of "M05 6, Mon"Image link .
Just a update to my code:
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

crop_agetxt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            Utils.HideKeyboard(FarmInputs.this);
            DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(FarmInputs.this, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
                    sowingDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
                    sowingDateDb = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
                    crop_agetxt.setText(sowingDate);
                    try {
                        cropAge = GetDays(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
                    } catch (ParseException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            datePicker.setCancelable(false);
            datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.days60_millisecond);
            datePicker.show();
        });

private String GetDays(String sowingdate) throws ParseException {
        Date userDob = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy", Locale.getDefault()).parse(sowingdate);
        Date today = new Date();
        assert userDob != null;
        long diff = today.getTime() - userDob.getTime();
        int numOfDays = (int) (diff / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
        System.out.println("GetDays: " + numOfDays);
        return String.valueOf(numOfDays);
    }


can you please tell how you are initialising cal??

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Could you also please follow the Java naming conventions? It would make it decidedly easier to read your code. Variable names and method names start with a lower case letter.

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getDefault());

just remove TimeZone.getDefault() and try once @Shiyaam

It isn't working; the calendar heading still displays M05 24, Fri (considering today's date)
i need like Fri May 24

I think this a app level issue ..just try this same on new dummy project and check whether you getting same output or not @Shiyaam . if getting same output then try changing the device

Let me try and post the result

I don't think this is possible using a DatePickerDialog. If your app doesn't have any localization, you could change the locale every time the app starts to one that has the correct date format. But if you do have localization, there's probably no other option than to search for a library that supports more customization.

I tried the exact same code in a new project by just adding a TextView that opens the calendar when clicked. In the new project, I got the format I expected. However, I don't know why I am not getting the same result in my existing project

@Wini should i do anything with device locale?

@Shiyaam Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

@Wini Not working

Thank you for helping me, hope the issue will be solved and post the solution

@Shiyaam can you check whether this format M05 6, Mon has been assigned or initialised or not anywhere in the entire project

it seems a very small issue...so you need figure out by going through the entire base level of the project ...@Shiyaam

Even though the date picker was designed for use with Calendar, I recommend that you use java.time, the modern Java date and time API, for your date work. You need a LocalDate for the date. Also stay far away from the SimpleDateFormatclass used in the answers. It’s a notorious troublemaker of a class. Use a modern DateTimeFormatter for formatting your LocalDate.

When you get M05 6, Mon, I figure it’s because of funny locale data on your Android device. You may be able to fix it by specifying a different locale somewhere. And other users with other devices may not experience it at all.

Don’t pass the selected date as a String to your method. Pass a LocalDate and save formatting and parsing back for simpler code. And for a correct count use ChronoUnit.DAYS.between() to count the days between two LocalDate instances.

Thank you all for taking the time to read this question and provide your answers. I have solved the issue, which was caused solely by the locale settings. I will post the answer and the update code i have used. Please review it and share your thoughts on that

Finally I solved the issue. Please refer the approach I have used and please let me know your toughts on this.
Original Issue:
The original issue was that the DatePickerDialog displayed dates in different formats depending on the locale settings. To ensure the DatePickerDialog consistently displays dates in the desired locale (e.g., en_US), we needed to temporarily set the locale for the dialog and then restore the original locale after the dialog is dismissed.
Code:
import android.content.res.Configuration;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH);

crop_agetxt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Utils.HideKeyboard(FarmInputs.this);

    // Save the current locale
    Locale currentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

    // Set the desired locale
    Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US"); // Example locale (US English)
    Locale.setDefault(locale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = locale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(FarmInputs.this, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            sowingDate = dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year;
            sowingDateDb = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;
            crop_agetxt.setText(sowingDate);
            try {
                cropAge = GetDays(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            // Restore the original locale
            Locale.setDefault(currentLocale);
            Configuration config = new Configuration();
            config.locale = currentLocale;
            getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
        }
    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    datePicker.setCancelable(false);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.days60_millisecond);
    datePicker.show();

    // Restore the original locale when the dialog is dismissed
    datePicker.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
        Locale.setDefault(currentLocale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = currentLocale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    });
});

Key Changes and Their Explanation:
Save the Current Locale:
Locale currentLocale = getResources().getConfiguration().locale;

We save the current locale so that we can restore it after the DatePickerDialog is dismissed.
Set the Desired Locale:
Locale locale = new Locale("en", "US"); // Example locale (US English)
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, 
getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

We set the desired locale (in this case, en_US) before showing the DatePickerDialog. This ensures that the dialog displays the date in the specified format.
DatePickerDialog Initialization:
DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(FarmInputs.this, R.style.calendar_theme, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
        // Date selection logic...
        // Restore the original locale
        Locale.setDefault(currentLocale);
        Configuration config = new Configuration();
        config.locale = currentLocale;
        getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
    }
}, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

Restore the Original Locale:
After setting the date, we restore the original locale inside the onDateSet method and when the dialog is dismissed:
Locale.setDefault(currentLocale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = currentLocale;
getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

We use an OnDismissListener to ensure the original locale is restored even if the user dismisses the dialog without selecting a date:
datePicker.setOnDismissListener(dialog -> {
    Locale.setDefault(currentLocale);
    Configuration config = new Configuration();
    config.locale = currentLocale;
    getResources().updateConfiguration(config, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());
});

Summary
This approach ensures that the DatePickerDialog displays dates in the desired locale format (en_US) and then restores the original locale after the dialog is dismissed, maintaining consistency in the date format displayed within the dialog while preserving the application's locale settings.

agetxt.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    Utils.HideKeyboard(FarmInputs.this);
    DatePickerDialog datePicker = new DatePickerDialog(FarmInputs.this, 0, new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {
            // Format the date
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.set(year, month, dayOfMonth);
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("E, MMM d", Locale.ENGLISH);
            Date = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

            // Set the formatted date
            agetxt.setText(Date);
            DateDb = year + "-" + (month + 1) + "-" + dayOfMonth;

            // Calculate age
            try {
                Age = GetDays(dayOfMonth + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, cal.get(Calendar.YEAR), cal.get(Calendar.MONTH), cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

    datePicker.setCancelable(false);
    datePicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() + Constants.days60_millisecond);
    datePicker.show();
});

Try This Way.

Actually, the issue arises when I run the exact same code in a new project, simply by adding a TextView and an OnClickListener. It works, and I get the exact format I need. However, when I use the same code in my ongoing project, the format appears differently.

When I asked ChatGPT, it responded:
"The difference in date format you're observing between your dummy project and your actual project could be due to the locale settings of your device or the default locale of your application.
In Android, the default date format displayed by DatePickerDialog can be influenced by the device's locale settings. Additionally, your application might have its own locale settings that could affect how dates are formatted."

wait I will try in my old project.

not to worry. this encouraged me to try something new.

sorry bro because I get the same result in my old project and as well as new projects.

Not a problem bro and I got my issue solved and posted the solution and Thank you once again.
